# cloudformation and GET requests

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have a cloudformation template that does many things, amongst which it's setting up a GET end point integrated with lambda. After a lot of head banging, i ran across:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-template-invoke-error/

I am really struggling to believe what i am reading and can't really believe that this article is correct. What's the point of having a complicated framework that can't integrate GET requests?

Otherwise my cloudformation does everything as it should (if i set up the same apigw + lambda manually, it will work, including lambda code).

Here is the error on the api GW side:

```
(80390c37-5d4a-46cb-b7f0-e38684943499) Lambda invocation failed with status: 403. Lambda request id: a9aef03f-9d94-41d1-941e-c7c69581467d
(80390c37-5d4a-46cb-b7f0-e38684943499) Execution failed due to configuration error:
```

The lambda code does not get executed

This is the API GW configuration

[image]

And this is the integration configuration:

[image]

Comment: You are confusing the requests hitting the API Gateway and the request from the API Gateway to the Lambda. A GET request to the API Gateway will be a POST request to the Lambda, everything will be POST to the lambda and the lambda knows based on the event what the actual incoming request was. => The integration needs be use POST but that is unrelated to what HTTP Methods the actual API Gateway understands in terms of what a client can send: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS,...

Comment: okay let me add more details to the question then, maybe this will help thanks

Comment: No need to add more detail. What you encountered here is the difference between what the simplified AWS Console UI shows and what the code can do. The UI simply automatically sets POST as the http integration method. When you deploy it via code you need to do that yourself.

Comment: thanks, but how? my understanding of what you are saying is that i am sending a GET request to lambda?

Comment: Currently you do, because you probably configured it that way in cloudformation or it is the default, I do not know since you have not shown your CF code. But what you need to do is specify POST as e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-integrationhttpmethod or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-integration.html#cfn-apigatewayv2-integration-integrationmethod

Comment: And in fact you are absolutely right, IntegrationHttpMethod was set to GET. If you answer it i will mark it as accepted solution. Thanks for your help appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241899/discussion-between-lordvee-and-luk2302).